# Exceptions in crash-dumps

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, exception

I have a Crash Dump from a Windows Executable (a .DMP file that opens well in WinDbg).

While I can read the stack, interpret some of the registers, and examine heap memory, I suspect there is an unhandled exception in play here as well.

What does an exception "look like" in memory?
Is it certain values in registers, or a certain state of the stack?
How do I find this and interpret it?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried using the `!analyze -v` command?

Answer (score 1):

type [.ecxr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the current exception displayed - it jumps to the source code, and call stack.

I thought it did it automatically, but that could just be the way I have it set up.